# Error while updating Nuget for Bot Framework

Tags: visual-studio, botframework, nuget-package, azure-bot-service

Error - Unable to resolve dependencies.

> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.1.4' is not compatible with
>   'Microsoft.Bot.Builder 3.8.1 constraint:
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt (>= 4.0.4.403061554 && < 5.0.0).

Will removing the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt have any sort effect on the project ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is that your solution is a using a newer version of the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` assembly than the ones expected by the BotBuilder Nuget.

To solve the problem:

1. Uninstall the current `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` Nuget from your solution
2. Install the BotBuilder Nuget. This should add a new reference to `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`

Comment: How about not updating it(System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt) at all @Ezequiel Jadib ?

Comment: If you were updating just that Nuget, then yes, you shouldn't. Let the BotFramework Nuget to manage its dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @Ezequiel Jadib!